# Fix scatter plot in PCA

Tags: python, scatter-plot, pca

I would like to get plot like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEl3w.png)

with this code:

```
plt.scatter(x=proj_wine[:,0], y = proj_wine[:,1], c=Labels, edgecolor= 'none', alpha=0.5)
```

but the **error is in the label**. What should I do to fix the labels? Any suggestion about this? I hope someone can help me to solve this. I am new in python. Thank you

Expecting I would get the plot like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6P08.png)